# Error while installing PyQt5: const class QJsonValue’ has no member named ‘toInt’

Tags: python, c++, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to install PyQt5 but I'm getting this error, I read some other posts related to this error but none of them helped.

```
/home/pathname/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/QtCore/sipQtCoreQJsonValue.cpp:367:30: error: ‘const class QJsonValue’ has no member named ‘toInt’
             sipRes = sipCpp->toInt(a0);
                              ^
make[1]: *** [sipQtCoreQJsonValue.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pathname/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1/QtCore'
make: *** [sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I installed Qt5 in my home folder and when I did `python configure.py` I included `qmake` to the path of which Qt5 is at and there was no problem with it. But with the `make` command I'm getting that error.

Comment: Are you sure that the version of Qt you have available to the make system is the right version for the PyQt you are building?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, my Qt version was older than the PyQt so I just had to get the new Qt version, now everything is installed correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Ah excellent, i made this into an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Qt you have available to the make system must be incompatible with the version of PyQt you are building.